# ScalaFX Button => How to define the action?

Tags: scala, javafx, scalafx

I'm trying to definde the **onAction** accion for a **Button** done in **scalafx** but I can't make it to work.

```
package App.Desktop

import javafx.event.EventHandler

import scalafx.event.ActionEvent

import scalafx.scene.control.Button

class Window() {

  btn_YES.onAction = (event: ActionEvent) => 
   new EventHandler[ActionEvent] {
     override def handle(event: ActionEvent) {
        /*Do something*/
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I've done this but I get an error

```
Error: type mismatch;
 found   : scalafx.event.ActionEvent => javafx.event.EventHandler[scalafx.event.ActionEvent]
 required: javafx.event.EventHandler[javafx.event.ActionEvent]
  btn_YES.onAction = (event: ActionEvent) => new EventHandler[ActionEvent]
```

I also tried to use the `javafx.event.ActionEvent` instead of `scalafx` but it doesn't work either.

Any clue?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not a Scala programmer, but it looks like you are mixing two different forms here: a lambda expression and an explicit class.

Try

```
package App.Desktop

import javafx.event.EventHandler

import javafx.event.ActionEvent

import scalafx.scene.control.Button

class Window() {

    btn_YES.onAction = 
        new EventHandler[ActionEvent] {
            override def handle(event: ActionEvent) {
                /*Do something*/
            }
        }

}
```

or

```
package App.Desktop

import javafx.event.EventHandler

import javafx.event.ActionEvent

import scalafx.scene.control.Button

class Window() {

  btn_YES.onAction = (event: ActionEvent) =>  {
        /*Do something*/
  }

}
```

Comment: Good answer, but you should also add `import scalafx.Includes._` - it will add some implicit conversions, which I think is necessary for the second version (with a function rather than an `EventHandler`). Generally speaking, this import should always be used in ScalaFX code.

Answer (score 4):

Fist, working with ScalaFX it is important to import `scalafx.Includes._`. It brings in many ScalaFX features.

There are two recomended ways to add `onAction` handler. The main one is to use `(event:ActionEvent) => { ... )` closure:

```scala
import scalafx.Includes._
import scalafx.event.ActionEvent

btn_YES.onAction = (event: ActionEvent) =>  {
  /*Do something*/
}
```

If you do not care about `event` object. You can save some typing and use `handle {...}`:

```scala
import scalafx.Includes._

btn_YES.onAction = handle {
  /*Do something*/
}
```

In both cases you need to import `scalafx.Includes._`

Answer (score 0):

You can use this for button action,

```
btn_YES.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
    @Override
    public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
            //Do some action here
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I am tried

```
Import scalafx.Includes._
import scalafx.event.ActionEvent

btn_YES.onAction = (event: ActionEvent) =>  {
  /*Do something*/
}
...

import scalafx.Includes._

btn_YES.onAction = handle {
  /*Do something*/
}
```

on javafx.scene.SubScene.setOnKeyPressed (..), setOnMouseEntered(..) it definitely does NOT WORK.

```
new EventHandler[KeyEvent]() {
      override def handle(event:KeyEvent){...}
}
```

that work for me.